# How does normal force act on ring with a point mass on it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, point-particles

I have been thinking about this situation, I have no idea how the normal force act of such a body.

Here I have taken the point mass and ring of same mass m but please provide a general solution.

So I will state it as a question:

How will normal force of the floor act on the ring of mass m and radius R, with a point mass on it when released is the same position as I have given in the picture. And ofcourse gravity is acting on it, take it g.

[image: The ring is of, suppose same mass as the point mass, here m]

Comment: without any tangential reaction, this condition can stand static equilibrium. You have to solve the dynamical equations. Is this the case?

Comment: "How does normal force act on ring with a point mass on it?" - what do you mean by "how" ? The normal force acts vertically upwards and has a magnitude equal to the combined weight of the point mass and the ring. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: @gandalf61 I actually meant, how it will actually affect the body. But now I have begin to understand it, I was not able to connect it with what i see in real life. The motion is clear but how?

Comment: @basics The center of mass will be at the mid point of com of the ring and the point mass, gravity will act on this point, if we look, normal force will apply toque on about that point. It will roll forward, I know that but I am not able to explain it... How is this motion exectly talking place?

Comment: @SAM4RTH I have added an answer below.

Comment: so change your question to ask for the equation of motion of this system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal force acts vertically upwards and has a magnitude equal to the combined weight of the point mass and the ring. The weight of the ring acts vertically downwards through its centre, but the weight of the point mass acts to one side of the centre and so creates a torque which makes the ring rotate.

If there is no friction between the ring and the ground then the ring will rotate in place because there is no horizontal force acting on the ring. However, if there is friction then this provides a horizontal force on the ring which causes the ring to roll to the right.

Note that all of this treats the problem as a two-dimensional problem and ignores stability in the direction perpendicular to the ring i.e. it is assumed that the ring is held upright in some way.